# how to merge two arrays if their value match?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

`$array1` keeps `cat_id` and `cat_title`

`$array2` keeps category id `(chck_cat_id)` and user id `(chck_comp_id)`. And if there is such array it means that user can reach that category.

What I want is if user has permission to that category, adding his id to first array.

If I need to show this visually:

[image: Arrays]

I have tried functions like `array_merge()`, `array_combine()` etc. but  it didn't merge arrays as I wanted to.

I actually suspect that if there is any built-in function for this?

How can I success what I want to?

Comment: You literally just asked that 30 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36458949/3933332 ...

Comment: Can you please add the PHP array in your question? You should provide the code directly, not an image of it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/303816#303816

Comment: Check here http://codepad.org/09W5sfjz

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it more complicated than it have to be.
Easiest way would probably be to use a `for`-loop with a `if` check.
Something like:

```
if($arr1[$i]['cat_id'] === $arr2['chck_cat_id']) {
  $arr1[$i]['user_id'] = $arr2['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example with `array_filter`

```
array_filter($array1, function ($entry) use ($array2) {
    return ($array2[0]['check_cat_id'] == $entry['cat_id']);
});
```